# How to set variable in jsp using jstl from input tag on same page?

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I want to do something like

```
<from action="#">
    <input type="number" name="id1">
    .......
<form>
<c:set var="quantity" value="//value from input field here"/>
```

Is it possible?
Note: whole code is a single jsp file

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean wanting to get the submitted value of the `input`, you can do something like this:

`<c:set var="user" value="${param.id1}" />`

Comment: Tried it but always end up with no value